# Cassandra com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException

Tags: java, cassandra, key-value-store, cassandra-3.0, nosql

I have been struggling to make Cassandra work. It works fine with small tests but as soon as I scale it works for a while but then fails. Loading of the data is not problem but it fails when the database is queried. As said it works well for a little while and afterwards it displays the following message.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx] Connection has been closed), xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx] Connection has been closed), xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx] Connection has been closed), xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx [only showing errors of first 3 hosts, use getErrors() for more details])

All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx] Connection has been closed), xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx] Connection has been closed), xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [xxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:xx] Connection has been closed),  [only showing errors of first 3 hosts, use getErrors() for more details])
```

**VERSION**

Cassandra 3.0, using java driver 3.0.0

**GENERAL SETTINGS**

4 exclusive local linux clusters for testing with default MAX_HEAP_MEMORY

**SESSION AND CLUSTER CREATION**

```
LoadBalancingPolicy loadBalancingPolicy = new RoundRobinPolicy();

SocketOptions socketOptions = new SocketOptions();
socketOptions.setConnectTimeoutMillis(900000000);
socketOptions.setReadTimeoutMillis(900000000);

PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
poolingOptions
      .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 32768)
      .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2000)
      .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 1000)
      .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 1000)
      .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 1000)
      .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 1000)
      .setNewConnectionThreshold(HostDistance.LOCAL, 128)
      .setNewConnectionThreshold(HostDistance.REMOTE, 128);

cluster = Cluster.builder()
      .addContactPointsWithPorts(addresses)
      .withLoadBalancingPolicy(loadBalancingPolicy)
      .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setFetchSize(100000))
      .withSocketOptions(socketOptions)
      .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
      .build();

session = cluster.connect();
```

**TABLE CREATION** -> This works fine tables are properly created and loaded

```
session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS KEYSPACE_NAME WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 4};");
session.execute("USE KEYSPACE_NAME;");
String query =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS KEYSPACE_NAME.TABLE_NAME 
        ( key blob PRIMARY KEY, 
          value blob 
          ) WITH caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'ALL' };";
```

session.execute(query);

**QUERYING**

```
Select.Where statement1 = qb.select().from(TABLE_NAME).where(QueryBuilder.in(primaryKey, QueryBuilder.bindMarker()));
pstatement= session.prepare(statement1).setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

ByteBuffer test = (ByteBuffer) getCassandraKey(key, k);
BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(pstatement).bind(test);
ResultSet results = session.execute(boundStatement);

session.execute(statement);
```

**CLOSING**

Session and Cluster are only closed once at the end of the application

**System.log**

*NODE 1*

```
INFO  [SharedPool-Worker-3] 2016-03-24 11:32:54,099 Message.java:605 - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0x63d065f4, /xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx :> /xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx]
java.io.IOException: Error while read(...): Connection reset by peer
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.readAddress(Native Method) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel$EpollSocketUnsafe.doReadBytes(EpollSocketChannel.java:675) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel$EpollSocketUnsafe.epollInReady(EpollSocketChannel.java:714) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:326) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:264) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:8694] 2016-03-24 11:51:08,496 AutoSavingCache.java:386 - Saved KeyCache (2444860 items) in 2389 ms
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 11:51:24,546 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 12:51:24,550 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 13:51:24,553 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 14:51:24,556 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:8789] 2016-03-24 15:51:08,410 AutoSavingCache.java:386 - Saved KeyCache (2444860 items) in 2303 ms
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 15:51:24,559 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
```

*NODE 2*

```
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 00:51:55,690 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 01:51:55,693 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 02:51:55,696 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:8486] 2016-03-24 03:51:29,706 AutoSavingCache.java:386 - Saved KeyCache (2295232 items) in 2190 ms
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 03:51:55,698 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 04:51:55,701 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 05:51:55,704 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 06:51:55,707 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:8583] 2016-03-24 07:51:29,623 AutoSavingCache.java:386 - Saved KeyCache (2295232 items) in 2099 ms
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 07:51:55,710 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 08:51:55,712 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 09:51:55,714 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 10:51:55,718 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:8679] 2016-03-24 11:51:29,699 AutoSavingCache.java:386 - Saved KeyCache (2300663 items) in 2174 ms
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 11:51:55,721 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 12:51:55,724 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 13:51:55,727 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 14:51:55,730 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:8774] 2016-03-24 15:51:29,786 AutoSavingCache.java:386 - Saved KeyCache (2300663 items) in 2258 ms
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2016-03-24 15:51:55,733 IndexSummaryManager.java:257 - Redistributing index summaries
```

Comment: your "QUERYING" section contains the table creation script

Comment: Your getting "Connection has been closed" exceptions, which means for some reason C* is dumping the connections.  Can you include any errors from your system.log?

Comment: Maybe try just not setting any PoolingOptions. Some of those settings look pretty off the wall (MaxRequestsPerConnection). You really should just leave all that alone and fine tune things after you have a working starting point.

At this point should maybe try things with 3.0.4 or 3.3 (maybe 3.4) to be on little more stable footing.

How are you scaling it? adding new dedicated systems? How big are the systems?

Comment: System.log from one of the nodes at the moment of crash in the post.

Comment: Before I was just using the default but I had the same problems that's why I increased the numbers. So far we are trying in our own clusters, they are big enough I think, 256GB. I am using the latest release available in mvn. We had the same problem with 2.0 so I updated.

Comment: It seems like the network packet loss issue, we experienced in production environment. Check and confirm there are no packet loss in network connection. Nodes to nodes , and nodes to application server. Looks like, cassandra works fine, but when network issue happens, it keeps rebuilding connection.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I tried with standard PoolingOptions and it did not work, it asked me to increase the number of per host connections  All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: xxxx/xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout while trying to acquire available connection (you may want to increase the driver number of per-host connections)))